# TypeError: sourceAsset.isNative is not a function when calling strictSendPaths

Tags: javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk, paths

I am trying to call a payment strict send path:

```
var server = new StellarSdk.Server("https://horizon.stellar.org", {
    allowHttp: false,
    appName: "Horizon",
    appVersion: "0.23"
  });

  var sourceAsset = new StellarSdk.Asset(
    "USD",
    "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX"
  );

  var sourceAmount = "0.0846227";

  var destination = [new StellarSdk.Asset("XLM", "")];

  console.log(sourceAsset.isNative());

  server
    .strictSendPaths(sourceAmount, sourceAsset, destination)
    .call()
    .then(function(pathResult) {
      console.log(pathResult.records);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

The error occurs at `new StrictSendPathCallBuilder (stellar-sdk.js:45400)`:

45400: `if (sourceAsset.isNative()) {`

The `console.log(sourceAsset.isNative());` in the code above runs well. I wonder what is causing the error in the Sdk.

A counter strict receive path request would be:

```
var server = new StellarSdk.Server("https://horizon.stellar.org", {
    allowHttp: false,
    appName: "Horizon",
    appVersion: "0.23"
  });

  var source = [new StellarSdk.Asset("XLM", "")];

  var destinationAsset = new StellarSdk.Asset(
    "USD",
    "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX"
  );
  console.log(destinationAsset.isNative());

  var destinationAmount = "1";

  server
    .strictReceivePaths(source, destinationAsset, destinationAmount)
    .call()
    .then(function(pathResult) {
      console.log(pathResult);
      console.log(pathResult.records);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

And that runs well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter order is wrong, it should be:

`strictSendPaths(sourceAsset, sourceAmount,  destination)`

Comment: That answers it. Thank you.